# How to give a score for each user in django

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-views

i'm beginner in django and i have a problem in this project, my goal is to make each user give a score from 1-10 to eachother. My question is how can i make "granted_by" to give a score "nota" to "granted_to" excluding itself. I don't know how to write it in views and use it in the template. Before giving me a - for asking a stupid and easy question, please take a peak to my code.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


VALUE = (
    (1, "Nota 1"),
    (2, "Nota 2"),
    (3, "Nota 3"),
    (4, "Nota 4"),
    (5, "Nota 5"),
    (6, "Nota 6"),
    (7, "Nota 7"),
    (8, "Nota 8"),
    (9, "Nota 9"),
    (10, "Nota 10"),
)


class Score(models.Model):
    granted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0)
    granted_to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0, related_name="granted_to")
    nota = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=VALUE)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render
from pro1 import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Punctaj



def Login(request):

    next = request.GET.get('next', '/home/')
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(next)  # render(request, "login/index.js")
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Inactive user.')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

    return render(request, 'login/login.html', {'redirect_to': next})


def Logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)


@login_required
def Home(request):
    user_list = User.objects.all()
    context = {

        "user_list": user_list,
    }
    return render(request, "login/home.html", context)
```

home.html

```
  <form class ="nota" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
      <h3>Scores</h3>

      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> User </th>
            <th> Scor </th>
            <th> Nota finala </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        {% for fotbalist in user_list %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ fotbalist.username }}</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="scor" min="1" max="10"></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><input type = "submit" value="submit"/></p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Unrelated to solve your problem, but I would make the names of your functions lowercase. It is common practice to have classes be CamelCase, and functions to be lowercase. (i.e. `class Foo():` or `def bar():`)

Comment: You're saying you need to have each of your users give each other a score, correct? So if you had 10 users, all 10 users would give each other a score - and you need to make sure that in addition to scoring each other, they don't give themselves a score?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your project.

Models.py

```
class Score(models.Model):
    granted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0)
    granted_to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0, related_name="granted_to")
    nota = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=VALUE)
```

View.py

```
class giveScoreView(FormView):
    template_name = 'give_score.html'
    form_class = giveScoreForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial_dict = {}
        initial_dict['user'] = self.request.user
        return initial_dict

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.granted_by = self.request.user
        form.save(commit=True)

    def get_success_url(self):
        url = "some return url"
        return url
```

Forms.py

```
class giveScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(giveScoreForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        loggedin_user = kwargs.get('initial').get('user')

        qs = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.filter().exclude(
                username=loggedin_user.username)

        self.fields['nota'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'id': 'nota',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'name': 'nota',
            'placeholder': 'Score',
            'required': True})

        self.fields['granted_to'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=qs,
            to_field_name='email',
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                       'required': True})
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Score
        fields = ['granted_to', 'nota']
```

give_score.html

```
<form id="lead-form" role="form" method="post" action="{% url "giveScoreView" %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>nota</label>
        {{form.nota}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>granted_to</label>
        {{form.granted_to}}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add</button>
</form>
```